# PHP - Malformed result from curl_exec()

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I've a problem with PHP function curl_exec(). I'm sending a SOAP request to an advice and the advice should return an SOAP reponse, but I just get a String without XML tags.

Okay, I'm using this code:

```
protected function _send_request($url,$post_string) {
    $soap_do = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );

    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $post_string);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) ));
    if ( ($result = curl_exec($soap_do)) === false) {
        echo curl_error($soap_do);
    } 
    else {
        echo("<pre>".$result."</pre>");
    }
}
```

And the code seems to work. I captured the network traffic with Wireshark and the reponse in the TCP package is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:tds=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl\" xmlns:tt=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema\">
    <s:Body>
        <tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
            <tds:SystemDateAndTime>
                <tt:DateTimeType>
                    Manual
                </tt:DateTimeType>
                <tt:DaylightSavings>
                    true
                </tt:DaylightSavings>
                <tt:TimeZone>
                    <tt:TZ>
                        CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3
                    </tt:TZ>
                </tt:TimeZone>
                <tt:UTCDateTime>
                    <tt:Time>
                        <tt:Hour>
                            13
                        </tt:Hour>
                        <tt:Minute>
                            26
                        </tt:Minute>
                        <tt:Second>
                            21
                        </tt:Second>
                    </tt:Time>
                    <tt:Date>
                        <tt:Year>
                            2014
                        </tt:Year>
                        <tt:Month>
                            2
                        </tt:Month>
                        <tt:Day>
                            5
                        </tt:Day>
                    </tt:Date>
                </tt:UTCDateTime>
                <tt:LocalDateTime>
                    <tt:Time>
                        <tt:Hour>
                            14
                        </tt:Hour>
                        <tt:Minute>
                            26
                        </tt:Minute>
                        <tt:Second>
                            21
                        </tt:Second>
                    </tt:Time>
                    <tt:Date>
                        <tt:Year>
                            2014
                        </tt:Year>
                        <tt:Month>
                            2
                        </tt:Month>
                        <tt:Day>
                            5
                        </tt:Day>
                    </tt:Date>
                </tt:LocalDateTime>
            </tds:SystemDateAndTime>
        </tds:GetSystemDateAndTimeResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now the problem. echo $result just returns

```
ManualtrueCET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3134622201425144622201425
```

The XML structure seems lost and I can't recreate it. I'm working with XAMPP PHP version 5.3.1 and the curl extension. Does anybody have an idea how to get the original XML structure?

Comment: If you are echoing that result in the browser, the browser is misinterpreting all those XML tags as HTML, and only showing you part of the result accordingly. Look at the browser's __page source_ and you will likely see your full XML.

Comment: You have it inside `<pre>` which will preserve line breaks, but you would need `htmlspecialchars()` to escape the `< >`.  Whenever you want to inspect any machine-readable string (or check that your PHP code produced the output expected) don't look at it as rendered in the browser. View the source instead.